# How can I improve bass lines with fingerstyle guitar playing?

Tags: guitar, fingerstyle-guitar

I have been learning fingerstyle guitar for a while and I can properly play songs with simple bass lines, but now I arrived to some songs with more difficult bass lines that don't sort of follow the main melody rhythm.

An example would be [this song](https://www.gametabs.net/kingdom-hearts/hollow-bastion), where the main melody has notes in each eighth but the bass line measure has two notes each 3 eighths and 2 notes each 2 eighths.

Other example can be fingerstyle blues songs that have a constant bass line but melody notes have a different rhythm [like here](https://youtu.be/V0FZzL9y55I).

Can I have some tips on improving this aspect of the fingerstyle playing? Maybe a book, or a keyword to easily find exercises online to practice this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study harmony, then counterpoint. Partimento is also a good training.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!